# Rmd to word with flex table - need to increase margins of ONLY the table in the word output

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown, flextable

I am building a routine report in Rmd that is outputted to word.
I have created a reference document to determine all the fonts and styles.
I am using flextable to create the table in this report.
The table needs to be wider than the margins of the rest of the word document.
Is there anyway to do this?

So far I am only getting the correct margins on the outputted table by increasing the margins in the reference document, but this isn't a great solution since the rest of the document, which is mostly text, needs to stay within certain margins.
I have tried increasing the width of the columns (width function for flextable), but that also doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: hi stib, could you provide a small reproducible example? it will increase your chances and speed of getting a good answer. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Table dimensions in Word are not constrained by page margins; not even by the paper size (though printouts risk omitting anything that doesn't fit the printable area). Hence there is no need to mess with the margins - which would require inserting Section breaks before & after the table. Simply either omit the table's 'preferred width' settings (& rely on the column widths), or make the 'preferred width' type and size whatever you want it to be.